# How to return NumberString's after a certain word

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm interested in the general operation of extracting [`NumberString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumberString.html)'s **after** a certain keyword.

Here is a specific example

Consider the string:

```
string = "5.45m total area (approx.): 73.8 sq. m (794.3 sq. ft)"
```

I want to extract $73.8$ and $794.3$ and perform some operation on them $f$

This following code returns $5.45$, which I don't want.

```
StringCases[
           string
           , (m : NumberString) :> f[m]
]
```

> ```
> {f["5.45"], f["73.8"], f["794.3"]}
> ```

## Attempt 1

```
StringCases[
           string
           , "total"~~___~~(m : NumberString) :> f[m]
]
```

> ```
>  {f["3"]}
> ```

this mysteriously returns the number $3$

## Question

Write some pattern `p` such that

```
StringCases[
           string
          , p
]
```

returns

> ```
>  {f["73.8"], f["794.3"]}
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer to Attempt1:

The "___" eats away as much as it can. Finally this leaves only: "3"

Answer to Question:

```
p = "total" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ m1 : NumberString ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ 
    m2 : NumberString :> {f[m1], f[m2]};
StringCases[string, p]
```

Note, this gives a double list. If you want a single list add "Flatten":

```
StringCases[string, p] // Flatten
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this! Is "___" set on `Longest[]` by default?

Comment: Ah, just found out from the documentation that ordinary expression patterns are `Shortest[p]` by default, while string patterns are `Longest[p]` by default.